# Catch 22 in deploying SharePoint WSP?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I deployed a WSP vis VS2008 WSPBuilder.
The WSP is to deploy a custom master page.
After deploying and activating the solution, I set the new custom master as the master.
When I try to surf to the application, I get an error.
I fixed the error in the file in VS2008, and deployed again (I did not deactivate the solution first, should I have?).
I then ran stsadm -o deletesolution -override, and it says it successfully deleted the solution.
I did an IISRESET, and I still cannot surf to the application.
Do I need to surf to the application to repair it, which I cannot do because I have an error (do I have a catch 22 issue?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that your problem is that your application is looking for a masterpage that doesn't exist in the file system since you deleted the WSP.

Try redeploying the WSP and see if your page comes back.

If not, see if you can browse directly to your site settings pages to see if you can change the master page back to something that works

http://siteurl/_layouts/settings.aspx

or

http://siteurl/_layouts/changesitemasterpage.aspx